# The tag "canon-1d" can't be created due to similarity with the "canon-1ds" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-naming

I'm trying to make the tags for the 1D and 1Ds family cameras more complete. The problem is that when I try to create the tag "canon-1d" the system complains due to similarities to the already created "canon-1ds" tag and gives me the following message:

> You are attempting to create the tag [canon-1d]; however the tag [canon-1ds] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta

So here I am raising it. I think the tag should be allowed for completeness.

Comment: The system probably sees the current one as a pluralization. I'm not, to be honest, actually sold on needing camera specific tags at all.

Comment: JoanneC: It probably does. I do understand that you're not too sold on the thought of having specific tags for all cameras. I just wanted to make it more complete since almost all Canon and Nikon cameras has specific tags for their models and they are frequently used in questions. I think the point you brought up is a great one for a separate discussion.

Comment: Perhaps, I may think about it some more before posing it. It's a bit of a "not broke, don't fix" for the most part, so I'm not sure it's worth it. In terms of this particular case, it likely requires SE folks to sort out if they can/want.

Comment: JoanneC: I think mods can add "plural" tags.

Comment: @mattdm - haven't checked if we can go the other direction though... :)